# Recover the displayed result of a formula

Tags: excel, vba, storage, formula, display

I try to retrieve the value displayed in cell:

```
Private Sub Check_Commentaires()

    'Declarations des variables
    Dim WB1 As Workbook
    Dim i, val2
    Dim val1 As Variant
    Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
    
    For i = 2 To 10000
        val1 = WB1.Sheets("Avant").Cells(i, 7).Value
        val2 = WB1.Sheets("Avant").Cells(i, 14).Value
        If (val1 = "#N/A" And val2 = "") Or (val1 = "0" And val2 = "") Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(4, 6).Value = "NOK"
            WB1.Close False
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(4, 6).Value = "OK"
        End If
    Next
        WB1.Close False
End Sub
```

but in this cell `(i,7)` I have `=recherchev(something...)` so it doesn't work with error message "type compatibility".

Any idea to store the result displayed in `WB1.Sheets("Avant").Cells(i, 7)` as a string?

Comment: If `WorksheetFunction.IsNA(val1)`, declaring `val1 As Variant`.

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve] including your variable declarations. How is `val1` and `val2` declared? • Also plaese include a description of what you are trying to do. What's your goal?

Comment: Same error 2042 on val1 with WorksheetFunction.IsNA(val1)

Comment: That's because `val1="0"` will fail with a Type Mismatch. Probably best to split that `If` up. You can't compare an error value to a String, thus `val1 = "0"` will throw a Type Mismatch error when `val1` is an error value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try replacing of:

```
       If (val1 = "#N/A" And val2 = "") Or (val1 = "0" And val2 = "") Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(4, 6).Value = "NOK"
            WB1.Close False
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(4, 6).Value = "OK"
        End If
```

with

```
  If IsError(val1) Then ' error
        If val1 = CVErr(2042) And val2 = "" Then 'N#A error and empty string in val2
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").cells(4, 6).Value = "NOK"
           wb1.Close False
           Exit Sub
        End If
  ElseIf val1 = "0" And val2 = "" Then                                'no error
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").cells(4, 6).Value = "NOK"
        wb1.Close False
        Exit Sub
  Else
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").cells(4, 6).Value = "OK"
  End If
```

`val2 = "0"` should mean that it is a 0 **string**. Is this your case?

Comment: Thanks you ! val2 = "0" was a mistake.

Comment: @NewCSharpWork OK. What about the other suggestion? I mean the final `WB1.Close` line... Doesn't the above suggestion work as you need?

Comment: It's working like i want, because I use exit sub if the first WB1.Close is trigger.

Comment: @NewCSharpWork That's correct. I missed that part and I looked only to the code I prepared... :). I will delete that part. And, eventually add it in the code answer...

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, `recherchev` is the dutch version of `VLookup`. This returns `#N/A` when nothing is found, but be aware that this is *not* the string `"#N/A"`, it's an *error* which is an own data type in VBA.

You can't compare an error with a string, you'll get a type mismatch.

As BigBen wrote in the comments, you can use `WorksheetFunction.IsNA(val1)` to check if it contains an error. However, if you change you If-statement to:

```
If (WorksheetFunction.IsNA(val1) And val2 = "") Or (val1 = "0" And val2 = "") Then
```

you will still get the same runtime error in case val1 holds `#N/A` because  of the second condition - `val1 = "0"` still throws that error. VBA will evaluate all parts of an If-statement, even if the first part is true (and therefore the whole If-condition is as `TRUE Or anything` will always be true).

Easiest solution for your case:

```
val1 = WB1.Sheets("Avant").Cells(i, 7).Value
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(val1) then val1 = 0
val2 = WB1.Sheets("Avant").Cells(i, 14).Value
If val1 = 0 And val2 = "" Then
   (...)
Else
   (...)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks you, and recherchev is the french version !

Comment: ... you should use the English formula names so that we don't have to guess or google it.